# Backing up files from corrupt disk from Windows Bootcamp

Tags: hard-drive, backup, bootcamp, disk-utility

So, mysteriously with no previous bad behavior my computer stopped booting, stuck in the gray loading bar cycle and then shutting down, the problem I believe wasn't obvious at first. I booted to recovery-mode (cmd+R) to access the disk utility and for my bad luck (terrible luck!) my hard drive was indeed failing and was not able to be fixed by disk-repair application. So, I'm willing to wipe the entire thing BUT as a software developer I've been working on a huge project on my own that never wanted to be anywhere outside my domain (hohoho!) , now I know it was a pretty dumb idea, because s**t happens. The thing is that I'm only looking forward to back up about a folder and that's it! And I was wondering if I could access my Mac partition from the Bootcamp Windows partition that is working completely fine, by the moment there's no disk unit identified on Windows. So.. Could I access the Mac-HD from my bootcamp partition so I could finally start wiping the thing out and re-installing OS while hitting my head against a wall for being so dumb?

I'd appreciate any kind of help. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is MacDrive, you'll be able to download a trial version for 5 days that should be enough to grab everything you need before formatting! Download it, install it on your windows partition, restart your computer, access Windows once again, open MacDrive and from there you can access your MacHD partition, if it's corrupt it will tempt you to fix it, you might as well try to, you never know, but if things don't go the way you wanted well just open the disk and try to reach for your most desired files! Copy them on a hard-drive and you are set to wipe everything! Of course if you really appreciate the software you might as well buy it! Good luck!